# How to solve $(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + 4\pi^2 C_3) y(x)=0,$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a some nice function so the everything in the following make sense.

We consider the following IVP:

\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} + 4\pi^2 C_3\right) y\left(x\right)&=0,&
y\left(0\right)&= C_1 \;\text{ and }\; y'\left(0\right)=\dfrac{d}{dx} \,y\left(0\right)= C_2.
\end{align}

($C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb R, C_3 \geq 0$)

> My Question: How to solve the above IVP?

Vague Idea: I think, I  have to apply this [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions) (Second-order, linear, inhomogeneous, constant coefficients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Your equation is
$$
y''+\omega^2y=0
$$
with $\omega^2=2\pi C_3$, $y_0=C_1$ and $y'_0=C_1$.
This is the equation of harmonic oscillator and the general solution is
$$y(t) = A \cos(\omega x) + B \sin(\omega x)$$
or 
$$y(t) = C \sin(\omega x+\phi)$$

See for example [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph5B/sho09.pdf).